# How to add translation for document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, paperclip, activeadmin, globalize

I have a table called 'documents' which has attachment (by paperclip gem), and I want to add translation for this attachment (by globalize gem) to be used in Activeadmin.
So once I open the document page in the active admin, I would like to add two or more translations of the document but for the same model (same model id but only locales changes).

The schema create table DB table of Document model is:

```
create_table "documents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.string   "doc_file_name"
    t.string   "doc_content_type"
    t.integer  "doc_file_size"
    t.datetime "doc_updated_at"
    t.integer  "model_id"
  end
```

and the database is postgres.

Comment: Do you want to transalate the table, the document or when you show that table on a view?

Comment: I just want to translate the document to get it by model_id & locale

Comment: oh , i see. Then time to check I18n internationalization.

Comment: gem 'globalize' helps you to have model_translations table in your database, what duplicates entire model instance. I think your paperclip can be in that separate model as what it does is just makes full clone of your initial model. I've done this in several projects. If your picture is going to stay same, but your picture attributes (i.e. picture description etc..) you want to change, this gem is the way to go imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solve it by removing the attachment 'doc' from the documents table then Creating translation table for documents using globalize gem `Document.create_translation_table!` and add:

```
has_many :docs
 class Translation
    belongs_to :document
    has_attached_file :doc, MODEL_DOCUMENTS_STORAGE_OPTIONS
    validates_attachment_content_type :doc, content_type: ['application/pdf']
  end
```

to the document model, then finally access it (create / update) by active admin form:

```
form :html => { :enctype => 'multipart/form-data' } do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.translated_inputs 'ignored title', switch_locale: false do |t|
        t.input :doc, :as => :file
      end
    end
    actions
  end
```